# Ninject + .NET 4 + Integrated Pipeline results in NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, ninject-2, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have configured Ninject 2 in an ASP.NET 4.0 project (not MVC) however when I deploy the project to an IIS host it crashes with the following:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetEventCount(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent) +30
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +1481
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) +132
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +709
```

I have tested this again with a vanilla ASP.net Web Application and get the same crash with the following code:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    return Container;
}

private IKernel Container
{
    get
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SiteModule());
        var module = new OnePerRequestModule();
        module.Init(this);
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Has anyone else got Ninject working with ASP.net 4?

[UPDATE: 2010.11.03]

After doing some research it appears it may be something to do with the OnePerRequestModule() module, removing this however doesn't seem to resolve the problem I added it due at the suggestion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536007/ninject-oneperrequestbehaviour-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ninject 2, you use the [Ninject.Web](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web) extension ([see the complete set here](http://ninject.org/extensions)) and dont do any explicit config as you have here around `OnePerRequestModule` etc.

You don't do any web.config stuff either IIRC (I'm using [the MVC one](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) and you don't there)

Comment: I am using Ninject.Web, unfortunatly even after removing the reference to OnePerRequestModule() the same error occurs.

Comment: @Richard Slater: You doing the `.Load()` to pick up `Ninject.Web` ? Does looking in the loaded modules nder the debugger show it as loaded?

Comment: Looks like your answer was correct, and I did something wrong somewhere after commenting the contents of the module out, redeploying to the server then uncommenting and redeploying it all works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Richard Slater: Good to hear you're sorted. The intregration is a lot less painful in V2 compared to V1 - I guess looking at old posts and questions can make it seem messier than it is.

Comment: agreed, old posts on forums do make it tough, particularly as there is very little documentation for Ninject.web.